# C++ Format Specifier not working

Tags: c++, portaudio

In portaudio callback i am running loop till the **framesperbuffer** variable. through debugging the for loop variable named **cnt** is incrementing but format specifier printing 256 at first and then 0. even if is i use `tmp.Format(_TEXT("-%d-",3)` , i get 0 in the CString.

here is my piece of code, i am using visual studio 2010 and have also tried _T and _TEXT without which error is generated

```
float *inp=(float*)inputBuffer;
    float *outp=(float*)outputBuffer;
    CString  str;
    CString  tmp;
    for(unsigned int cnt=0; cnt< framesPerBuffer; cnt++)
    {
    tmp.Format(_TEXT("-%d-",cnt));
    str.Append(tmp);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a misplaced paren. You have the int argument to Format inside the _TEXT() macro argument list, so it's not being passed to Format at all

This should work better:

```
tmp.Format(_TEXT("-%d-"),cnt);
```